# Curve modifier - wrapping honeycomb mesh

Tags: modifiers

I am really struggling to get this to work. It seems very simple. Every time i mess with origins and axis', it always stays flat and i get a bunch of variations like this:
[image]

What i want to do is take this honeycomb mesh wrap around the simple curve in front of it:
[image]

so that it looks like this, but the honeycomb:
[image]

Where am i going wrong? Im assuming i am just missing some combination of axis, origins and Ctrl + A'ing something.

The Blend file: [image]

Comment: Settings all fine.. you have doubled-up control-points at both ends of your curve-thingy, which also flip direction there. So delete those to get a clean, curve in one direction. Took quite a time to find!

Comment: I salute to your sharp eye @Robin, couldn't crack it at all :).

Comment: Thanks man, that'll do it! I agree, good eye!